# How to store courses added from a y/n loop to a char in c

Tags: c

The code prints the list of courses the user entered using a for loop. Is there a way in which the list of courses can be saved to a single char file like

`printf("%s", listofcourses);`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_COURSES 5

int main(void)
{
    int selected_courses[NUM_COURSES];
    int num_selected_courses = 0;
    int c;

    const char * const list_courses[NUM_COURSES] = {
        "CSE1100",
        "CSE1101",
        "CSE1102",
        "ITE1100",
        "ITE1101"
    };

    do
    {
        bool input_valid = false;
        int selected_course;
        int d;

        while ( !input_valid )
        {
            char input[100];

            //prompt user for input
            printf(
                "Courses available:\n"
                " CSE1100\n"
                " CSE1101\n"
                " CSE1102\n"
                " ITE1100\n"
                " ITE1101\n"
                "\n"
                "Enter Course: "
            );

            //attempt to read one word of user input
            if ( scanf( "%99s", input ) != 1 )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "unexpected input failure!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //discard remainder of input line
            do
            {
                d = getchar();

            } while ( d != '\n' && d != EOF );

            //determine whether course entered was valid or not
            for( int i = 0; i < NUM_COURSES; i++ )
            {
                if ( strcmp(input, list_courses[i] ) == 0)
                {
                    input_valid = true;
                    selected_course = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if invalid, print error message
            if ( !input_valid )
                printf( "Invalid choice! Try again.\n\n" );
        }

        //input was valid, so add course
        selected_courses[num_selected_courses] = selected_course;
        num_selected_courses++;

        //if we have already reached the maximum number of
        //courses, then don't ask again
        if ( num_selected_courses == NUM_COURSES )
            break;

        //ask user whether he wants to add another course
        printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)\n"); 
        c = d = getchar();

        //add spacing
        printf( "\n" );

        //discard remainder of input line
        while ( d != '\n' && d != EOF )
            d = getchar();

    } while ( c == 'y' );

    printf( "You have selected the following courses:\n" );

    //print courses selected by user
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_selected_courses; i++ )
        printf( "%s\n", list_courses[selected_courses[i]] );
}
```

Comment: Open the file, and use `fprintf` similar to how you used `printf`, in the last two lines of the code.

Comment: Aside: when you showed the user a list of available courses, you could have output each string from the `const char * const list_courses[]` already defined, in a loop. Less hard coding, less maintenance.

Comment: I want to add the list of courses stored for a particular student using a struct  . So if the user adds a new student in the struct each student would have their own list of courses. How can this be possible?

Comment: @WeatherVane as in  the stored courses can be stored in a struct with an array

Comment: for eg say the list of courses were stored in a struct with ` char list_courses[100]`

Comment: @Link123: I believe that you may be confusing `list_courses` and `selected_courses`. The array `list_courses` is not supposed to change, but is supposed to simply contain a list of all available courses, whereas `selected_courses` is supposed to change, as it contains all courses the user has selected. Whenever the user selects a new course, it will get added to `selected_courses`.

Comment: what if the user enters `Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way in which the list of courses can be saved to a single char file

I assume that with "a single char file" you mean a single string.

Currently, you are storing the IDs (which are `int` indexes into the array `list_courses`) of all the courses that the user has selected, in the array `selected_courses`. At the end of the program, these IDs are individually read and converted into text, and printed to the screen. If you instead want to write them to a string, and then use

```
printf( "%s", string );
```

on that string afterwards, then this is possible (although I don't understand why you want to do that):

You can change the lines

```
//print courses selected by user
for ( int i = 0; i < num_selected_courses; i++ )
    printf( "%s\n", list_courses[selected_courses[i]] );
```

to:

```
//this buffer must be made large enough, otherwise a buffer overflow
//will occur
char string[200];

//set first character to null to make string empty
string[0] = '\0';

//fill string with list of courses
for ( int i = 0; i < num_selected_courses; i++ )
{
    //add a comma and a space if this is not the first in the list
    if ( i != 0 )
        strcat( string, ", " );

    //add course to string
    strcat( string, list_courses[selected_courses[i]] );
}

//print the string
printf( "String contents: %s\n", string );
```

The program now has the following behavior:

```
Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1100
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
y

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1102
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
y

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: ITE1100
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
n

You have selected the following courses:
String contents: CSE1100, CSE1102, ITE1100
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mbEXLxQ6Fvn9Fp1wgmy0ogcWWHn687SP/view?usp=sharing <-- This is the full program, it runs fine but when i enter another student it prints the list of courses from the previous student also. How do i get them to be seperate?

Comment: ___________________________________________

Comment: @Link123: If you want to use the variable `num_selected_courses` for more than one student, then you must reset it to zero before reading the courses for the new student. However, a cleaner solution would be to enclose the contents of `case 1` in a code block `{}` and declare and initialize the variable `num_selected_courses` there. This will limit the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) and [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) of the variable `num_selected_courses` to that of the code that handles a single student.

Comment: @Link123: On the other hand, the cleanest solution would probably be to make your own function for entering the details of a new student, instead of writing all that code into `main`, as the function `main` is getting very messy with all that code. You could then make the variables `num_selected_courses` and `selected_courses` (and also several other variables) local variables of that function. This will make your code much more tidy.