# Store list of courses input by user to an array in c

Tags: c

The program currently only asks the user to input courses, I want the list of courses the user entered to be stored in `struct Students{ char courses[NUM_COURSES][100];`. The list of courses the user entered should be able to be printed by using
`printf("Courses %s\n",temp->courses);`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_COURSES 5

int i = 0;
struct Students
{
    char first_name[100];
    char last_name[100];
    int age;
    char address[100];
    char programme[100];
    char courses[NUM_COURSES][100];
    int num_selected_courses;
    struct Students *next;
} * head;

void enter_student(char *first_name, char *last_name, int age, char *address, char *programme, char *courses, int num_selected_courses)
{
    struct Students *student = (struct Students *)malloc(sizeof(struct Students));
    strcpy(student->first_name, first_name);
    strcpy(student->last_name, last_name);
    student->age = age;
    strcpy(student->address, address);
    strcpy(student->programme, programme);
    strcpy(student->courses[i], courses);
    student->num_selected_courses = num_selected_courses;
    student->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        // if head is NULL
        // set student as the new head
        head = student;
    }
    else
    {
        // if list is not empty
        // insert student in beginning of head
        student->next = head;
        head = student;
    }
}
void search_fname(char *first_name, char *last_name, int age, char *address, char *programme, char *courses, int num_selected_courses)
{
    struct Students *temp = head;
    char a[50];
    int j;
    printf("Enter First Name of Student to Search:\n");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (!strcmp(first_name, a))
            {
                printf("The Students Details are:\n");
                printf("First Name: %s\n", temp->first_name);
                printf("Last Name: %s\n", temp->last_name);
                printf("Age:%d\n", temp->age);
                printf("Address: %s\n", temp->address);
                printf("Programme: %s\n", temp->programme);
                printf("Courses %s\n", temp->courses); /// list of courses  for student name entered prints here
                return;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("Student name %s not found!!!\n\n\n", a);
}
int main()
{
    struct Students stud;
    head = NULL;
    char first_name[100];
    char last_name[100];
    int age;
    char address[100];
    char programme[100];
    int selected_courses[NUM_COURSES];
    int num_selected_courses = 0;
    int c;
    const char *const list_courses[NUM_COURSES] = {
        "CSE1100",
        "CSE1101",
        "CSE1102",
        "ITE1100",
        "ITE1101"};
    do
    {
        int input_valid = 0;
        int selected_course;
        int d;

        while (!input_valid)
        {
            char input[100];

            // prompt user for input
            printf(
                "Courses available:\n"
                " CSE1100\n"
                " CSE1101\n"
                " CSE1102\n"
                " ITE1100\n"
                " ITE1101\n"
                "\n"
                "Enter Course: ");

            // attempt to read one word of user input
            if (scanf("%99s", input) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "unexpected input failure!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            // discard remainder of input line
            do
            {
                d = getchar();

            } while (d != '\n' && d != EOF);

            // determine whether course entered was valid or not
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COURSES; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(input, list_courses[i]) == 0)
                {
                    input_valid = 1;
                    selected_course = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if invalid, print error message
            if (!input_valid)
                printf("Invalid choice! Try again.\n\n");
        }

        // input was valid, so add course
        selected_courses[num_selected_courses] = selected_course;
        num_selected_courses++;

        // if we have already reached the maximum number of
        // courses, then don't ask again

        // ask user whether he wants to add another course
        printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)\n");
        c = d = getchar();

        // add spacing
        printf("\n");

        // discard remainder of input line
        while (d != '\n' && d != EOF)
            d = getchar();

    } while (c == 'y');

    for (int i = 0; i < num_selected_courses; i++)
    {
        // COPYING A SELECTED COURSE INTO STUDENT STRUCT
        strcpy(stud.courses[i], list_courses[selected_courses[i]]);
    }
    // POPULATE NUMBER OF SELECTED COURSES IN STUDENT STRUCT
    stud.num_selected_courses = num_selected_courses;

    printf("You have selected the following courses:\n");

    // PRINTING ALL COURSES IN THE STUDENT STRUCT
    for (int i = 0; i < stud.num_selected_courses; i++)
        // PRINTING A COURSE IN THE STUDENT STRUCT
        printf("%s\n", stud.courses[i]);
}
```

Comment: You have described what you want to do but you also need to describe what specifically prevents you from doing it. That is, what specific problem or error are you having with the code shown? Please review [ask].

Comment: I'd start by [fixing your warnings/errors.](https://godbolt.org/z/Eoz6Mnaex)

Comment: If, as you state in your question, you want the list of courses to be printable with the line `printf("Courses %s\n",temp->courses);`, then the `courses` member of `struct Students` must be a single string, instead of an array of strings. This probably means that you would have to build the string yourself, inserting the names of the courses into the string and maybe separating them with a comma or a space or both.

Comment: Are you sure that it must be printable with the line `printf("Courses %s\n",temp->courses);`? It would seem more meaningful to print it with `printf( "Courses %s\n", temp->courses[i] );` in a loop, with `i` being the loop counter. That way, one course could be printed per loop iteration, and you could keep the array of strings and would not require it to be a single string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use the line

```
printf("Courses %s\n",temp->courses);
```

in order to print the `courses` member of `struct Students`, then you must make the `courses` member a null-terminated string. However, you are currently declaring that member as an array of strings.

Therefore, in order to do what you say you want, you would have to change the declaration

```
char courses[NUM_COURSES][100];
```

in `struct Students` to something like:

```
char courses[100];
```

You probably want the content of the string to be something like:

`"CSE1100, CSE1102, ITE1101"`

I have shown you in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70639608/12149471) how to build such a string.